# Listening to a printer Port using Java socket programming

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am a newbie in Java and Socket programming .Can i use socket programming to read data from my server using a socket . I dont have a Server application Because data is taken from the printer port . I installed a network printer in the server and whenever my server prints to that specific printer i have to listen that port to get the print data.the client program is running on an android device and the server is a windows 2008 server . So that i can print the recieved data to a serial port printer attached android device .

Comment: The network printer has its own port in its own TCP/IP stack. You can't listen to that in the server. You might be able to intercept the print request some other way, or by configuring a pseudo-printer somehow with a port that is local to the server hardward that you can listen to, and forward to the real printer IP:port. But as stated, your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: is there any other way to do this one ?my server application is in C# and client application is in java..